# complex urdf files

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do most people end up creating their complex urdf and sdf files? Most of the tutorials I see edit the xml in their text editor of choice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328289/complex-urdf-files/) by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend either using the ros1 xacro (a bit clanky in my opinion) or to use some templating language like Jinja2 or empy, both of which are independent of ros/ros2. The advantages of using jinja2 or empy are that you can specify templates with parameters, and then use those templates as many times as you want. You can also include other template files into a new template.

Using a robotic arm for example, you could create a single "segment" template that creates a hing, with a rigid arm on the other end. The "segment" template would need to be parameterized such that you can specify where to attach the hing, and how long the segment is, etc.  Then you can create a new "Arm" template that pulls in multiple "segment" templates to build up a arm with several segments.

Once you have a template, you can write a python script that renders the urdf, and spits it out to be spawned by gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-12**:\

> The "segment" template would need to be parameterized such that you can specify where to attach the hing, and how long the segment is, etc. Then you can create a new "Arm" template that pulls in multiple "segment" templates to build up a arm with several segments.

like how `xacro` does this, you mean ? ;)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-12**:
As an example of using `empy`, see the way (the) O(S)R(F) created the worlds and parts for the ARIAC challenge: [osrf/ariac/src/osrf_gear/worlds/gear.world.template](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/ariac/src/master/osrf_gear/worlds/gear.world.template). It's just one example, but does illustrate the idea.

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2019-07-12**:
Correct. I've used Jinja2 in the past to create urdfs where each sensor type (gps, imu, camera, etc) was it's own template. When I needed to test a new sensor configuration, I could just include that template, and pass it the correct parameters of where to mount the sensor, frequency to publish data, topic to publish on, noise parameters, etc. It worked quite well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-12**:
Which again is exactly how it works with `xacro` :)

Not saying using something else cannot be beneficial, just making sure it's clear that that is not much different from how `xacro` works. See [ubi-agni/human_hand/model/human_hand.urdf.xacro](https://github.com/ubi-agni/human_hand/blob/387b970d9b024d11c50a9874a3ec401fe8c914ad/model/human_hand.urdf.xacro) for an example.

**Comment by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on 2019-07-12**:
Interesting, thanks for the recommendations.

I'm surprised that everyone seems to prefer defining their models in code rather than using some CAD tool that exports the model to the format of choice.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-12**:\

> I'm surprised that everyone seems to prefer defining their models in code

you have a sample size of 2 here (at least here on ROS Answers).

And this is coming from a community that consists of a lot of programmers.

> rather than using some CAD tool that exports the model to the format of choice.

that would be nice, but:

- most of those tools cost a lot of money
- it's way quicker to add an additional link by copy-pasting some text and adjusting some parameters than to fire up your cad tool (probably Windows only), loading the assembly, rearrange geometry, run an exporter and then fixing up / post processing whatever the exporter didn't do correctly
- anyone can edit text files, becoming proficient with a CAD tool is not as easy
- CAD tools typically don't use open formats, increasing vendor lock-in
- CAD tools don't necessarily support the domain concepts of robotics (ie: links, joints, limits, etc), reducing editing to editing of generic shapes

and so on.

..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-12**:
..

I'm not dismissing using more high-level modeling tools for this (and in fact, they *are* being used, see fi [sw_urdf_exporter](http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter) and [dfki-ric/phobos](https://github.com/dfki-ric/phobos)), it's just that in an environment that is so code heavy/centric, being able to generate models from parametric descriptions fits the overall development workflow a bit better.

All *in my opinion* of course.

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2019-07-12**:
I've never seen that phobos one.. It looks intriguing! I'll have to look into it! Thanks!

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30569/mogumbo/) on 2019-07-29**:
Does anyone have an example of using a .xacro file in a ros2 launch script? I have tried the ros2 branch of the official xacro repo (which doesn't compile) and 2 other forks of xacro for ros2 (which both give me runtime errors).

**Comment by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on 2019-07-30**:
I cloned https://github.com/kazuki0824/xacro.git and made a setup.py and a xacro resource file to the ros2 branch to get it working with dashing. No problems after that.